# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument when reading a .grib file with xarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-xarray, oserror

I'm trying to read a massive `grib` file with the `xarray` Python library and later in a cycle transform it into a `numpy` array with a different shape. An array with the required size is allocated successfully, and getting the values from the `grib` file works for approximately half of the file, but then it fails with

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Incorrect argument
```

On the thread

With `offset ==-5`, use `file.seek(offset)`. Direct access to the array before the cycle ends up with the same result, but somehow changes with other arguments in `xr.open_dataset**`-see the changes below.

Here's the full script:

```
# import cfgrib
import tqdm
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
from struct import unpack

files_path_prefix = 'D://Data/OceanFull/'
data_postfix = '2019-extended'

maskfile = open(files_path_prefix + "mask", "rb")
binary_values = maskfile.read(29141)
maskfile.close()
mask = unpack('?' * 29141, binary_values)
mask = np.array(mask, dtype=int)

# load grib
ds = xr.open_dataset(files_path_prefix + f'{data_postfix}.grib', engine='cfgrib')
print(ds)
print(ds.coords['valid_time'])
print(ds.coords['valid_time'].shape)

# sensible
shape = ds.variables['msshf'].shape
print(shape)
tmp = ds.variables['msshf']
tmp = tmp[:, :, ::2, ::2]  # part of map with size 161x181
print(tmp.shape)

print(tmp[370, :, 39, 39])  # ok
print(tmp[400, :, 39, 39])  # OSError without chunks=-1

sensible = np.zeros((161*181, shape[0] * shape[1]))
print(sensible.shape)
for t in tqdm.tqdm(range(shape[0])):
    for i in range(161):
        sensible[i * 181:(i + 1) * 181, t * shape[1]:(t+1)*shape[1]] = tmp[t, :, i, :].data.transpose()

sensible[np.logical_not(mask), :] = np.nan
np.save(files_path_prefix + f'SENSIBLE_{data_postfix}.npy', sensible)
```

Here's the full log:

```
"D:\Python projects\Ocean_components\venv_base\Scripts\python.exe" "D:/Python projects/Ocean_components/grib_handler.py"
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (time: 731, step: 12, latitude: 321, longitude: 361)
Coordinates:
    number      int32 ...
  * time        (time) datetime64[ns] 2018-12-31T18:00:00 ... 2019-12-31T18:0...
  * step        (step) timedelta64[ns] 01:00:00 02:00:00 ... 11:00:00 12:00:00
    surface     float64 ...
  * latitude    (latitude) float64 80.0 79.75 79.5 79.25 ... 0.75 0.5 0.25 0.0
  * longitude   (longitude) float64 -90.0 -89.75 -89.5 -89.25 ... -0.5 -0.25 0.0
    valid_time  (time, step) datetime64[ns] ...
Data variables:
    mslhf       (time, step, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    msshf       (time, step, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
Attributes:
    GRIB_edition:            1
    GRIB_centre:             ecmf
    GRIB_centreDescription:  European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts
    GRIB_subCentre:          0
    Conventions:             CF-1.7
    institution:             European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts
    history:                 2022-08-17T15:57 GRIB to CDM+CF via cfgrib-0.9.1...
<xarray.DataArray 'valid_time' (time: 731, step: 12)>
array([['2018-12-31T19:00:00.000000000', '2018-12-31T20:00:00.000000000',
        '2018-12-31T21:00:00.000000000', ..., '2019-01-01T04:00:00.000000000',
        '2019-01-01T05:00:00.000000000', '2019-01-01T06:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2019-01-01T07:00:00.000000000', '2019-01-01T08:00:00.000000000',
        '2019-01-01T09:00:00.000000000', ..., '2019-01-01T16:00:00.000000000',
        '2019-01-01T17:00:00.000000000', '2019-01-01T18:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2019-01-01T19:00:00.000000000', '2019-01-01T20:00:00.000000000',
        '2019-01-01T21:00:00.000000000', ..., '2019-01-02T04:00:00.000000000',
        '2019-01-02T05:00:00.000000000', '2019-01-02T06:00:00.000000000'],
       ...,
       ['2019-12-30T19:00:00.000000000', '2019-12-30T20:00:00.000000000',
        '2019-12-30T21:00:00.000000000', ..., '2019-12-31T04:00:00.000000000',
        '2019-12-31T05:00:00.000000000', '2019-12-31T06:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2019-12-31T07:00:00.000000000', '2019-12-31T08:00:00.000000000',
        '2019-12-31T09:00:00.000000000', ..., '2019-12-31T16:00:00.000000000',
        '2019-12-31T17:00:00.000000000', '2019-12-31T18:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2019-12-31T19:00:00.000000000', '2019-12-31T20:00:00.000000000',
        '2019-12-31T21:00:00.000000000', ..., '2020-01-01T04:00:00.000000000',
        '2020-01-01T05:00:00.000000000', '2020-01-01T06:00:00.000000000']],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
Coordinates:
    number      int32 ...
  * time        (time) datetime64[ns] 2018-12-31T18:00:00 ... 2019-12-31T18:0...
  * step        (step) timedelta64[ns] 01:00:00 02:00:00 ... 11:00:00 12:00:00
    surface     float64 ...
    valid_time  (time, step) datetime64[ns] 2018-12-31T19:00:00 ... 2020-01-0...
Attributes:
    standard_name:  time
    long_name:      time
(731, 12)
(731, 12, 321, 361)
(731, 12, 161, 181)
<xarray.Variable (step: 12)>
array([-107.482666,  -96.02222 ,  -57.2312  ,  -47.157227,  -40.70703 ,
        -20.342773,  -15.448486,  -14.494629,  -12.022217,   -6.519531,
         -0.410645,    2.542725], dtype=float32)
Attributes:
    GRIB_paramId:                             235033
    GRIB_dataType:                            fc
    GRIB_numberOfPoints:                      115881
    GRIB_typeOfLevel:                         surface
    GRIB_stepUnits:                           1
    GRIB_stepType:                            avg
    GRIB_gridType:                            regular_ll
    GRIB_NV:                                  0
    GRIB_Nx:                                  361
    GRIB_Ny:                                  321
    GRIB_cfName:                              unknown
    GRIB_cfVarName:                           msshf
    GRIB_gridDefinitionDescription:           Latitude/Longitude Grid
    GRIB_iDirectionIncrementInDegrees:        0.25
    GRIB_iScansNegatively:                    0
    GRIB_jDirectionIncrementInDegrees:        0.25
    GRIB_jPointsAreConsecutive:               0
    GRIB_jScansPositively:                    0
    GRIB_latitudeOfFirstGridPointInDegrees:   80.0
    GRIB_latitudeOfLastGridPointInDegrees:    0.0
    GRIB_longitudeOfFirstGridPointInDegrees:  -90.0
    GRIB_longitudeOfLastGridPointInDegrees:   0.0
    GRIB_missingValue:                        9999
    GRIB_name:                                Mean surface sensible heat flux
    GRIB_shortName:                           msshf
    GRIB_totalNumber:                         0
    GRIB_units:                               W m**-2
    long_name:                                Mean surface sensible heat flux
    units:                                    W m**-2
    standard_name:                            unknown
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python projects\Ocean_components\grib_handler.py", line 30, in <module>
    print(tmp[400, :, 39, 39])  # OSError
  File "D:\Python projects\Ocean_components\venv_base\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\common.py", line 159, in __repr__
    return formatting.array_repr(self)
  File "D:\Python projects\Ocean_components\venv_base\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\formatting.py", line 570, in array_repr
    data_repr = short_data_repr(arr)
  File "D:\Python projects\Ocean_components\venv_base\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\formatting.py", line 548, in short_data_repr
    return short_numpy_repr(array)
  File "D:\Python projects\Ocean_components\venv_base\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\formatting.py", line 520, in short_numpy_repr
    array = np.asarray(array)
  File "D:\Python projects\Ocean_components\venv_base\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\common.py", line 156, in __array__
    return np.asarray(self.values, dtype=dtype)
  File "D:\Python projects\Ocean_components\venv_base\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\variable.py", line 527, in values
    return _as_array_or_item(self._data)
  File "D:\Python projects\Ocean_components\venv_base\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\variable.py", line 267, in _as_array_or_item
    data = np.asarray(data)
  File "D:\Python projects\Ocean_components\venv_base\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py", line 653, in __array__
    self._ensure_cached()
  File "D:\Python projects\Ocean_components\venv_base\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py", line 650, in _ensure_cached
    self.array = NumpyIndexingAdapter(np.asarray(self.array))
  File "D:\Python projects\Ocean_components\venv_base\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py", line 623, in __array__
    return np.asarray(self.array, dtype=dtype)
  File "D:\Python projects\Ocean_components\venv_base\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py", line 524, in __array__
    return np.asarray(array[self.key], dtype=None)
  File "D:\Python projects\Ocean_components\venv_base\lib\site-packages\cfgrib\xarray_plugin.py", line 144, in __getitem__
    return xr.core.indexing.explicit_indexing_adapter(
  File "D:\Python projects\Ocean_components\venv_base\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py", line 815, in explicit_indexing_adapter
    result = raw_indexing_method(raw_key.tuple)
  File "D:\Python projects\Ocean_components\venv_base\lib\site-packages\cfgrib\xarray_plugin.py", line 150, in _getitem
    return self.array[key]
  File "D:\Python projects\Ocean_components\venv_base\lib\site-packages\cfgrib\dataset.py", line 342, in __getitem__
    message = self.index.get_field(message_ids[0])  # type: ignore
  File "D:\Python projects\Ocean_components\venv_base\lib\site-packages\cfgrib\messages.py", line 472, in get_field
    return ComputedKeysAdapter(self.fieldset[message_id], self.computed_keys)
  File "D:\Python projects\Ocean_components\venv_base\lib\site-packages\cfgrib\messages.py", line 332, in __getitem__
    return self.message_from_file(file, offset=item)
  File "D:\Python projects\Ocean_components\venv_base\lib\site-packages\cfgrib\messages.py", line 328, in message_from_file
    return Message.from_file(file, offset, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python projects\Ocean_components\venv_base\lib\site-packages\cfgrib\messages.py", line 91, in from_file
    file.seek(offset)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm using Windows 10 with 16Gb RAM, Python version 3.9, xarray-2022.6.0 (latest version, just upgraded), file size is about 3.9 Gb.

What I really don't understand-I tried using other arguments in the open_dataset function to load the full file into the memory:

```
ds = xr.open_dataset(files_path_prefix + f'{data_postfix}.grib', engine='cfgrib', chunks=-1, inline_array=True)
```

and this time it DOESN'T fails at

```
print(tmp[400, :, 39, 39])  # OSError
```

**but instead fails on the first iteration of the cycle starting from 400** (and I really have no idea, why):

```
for t in tqdm.tqdm(range(400, shape[0])):
    for i in range(161):
        sensible[i * 181:(i + 1) * 181, t * shape[1]:(t+1)*shape[1]] = tmp[t, :, i, :].data.transpose()
```

UPD:

1. The exact first problem index is 386. I tried commenting the slicing `tmp = tmp[:, :, ::2, ::2]` but it didn't change anything.
2. I traced the `open_dataset` function and found that **offset values equal to -5 appear first at this part of `open_file` function in `dataset.py`**:

```
    stream = messages.FileStream(path, errors=grib_errors)

    index_keys = compute_index_keys(time_dims, extra_coords)
    index = open_fileindex(stream, indexpath, index_keys, filter_by_keys=filter_by_keys)
```

Here the `index` variable already has the -5 values at `index.field_ids_index[10000]`, while `index.field_ids_index[1000]` is ok. I think, the problem lies in `messages.py` script and either the variable `stream` appearing here is badly constructed or the bug is in the function `open_fileindex`, where again the `messages.py` appear:

```
    index = messages.FileIndex.from_indexpath_or_filestream(
        stream, index_keys, indexpath=indexpath, computed_keys=computed_keys
    )
```